# Selecting item from dropdownlist in c# asp.net [iOS]

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, ipad

I'm programming a website in asp.net c# which contain a dropdownlist inside the GridView, of this nature.

Please find the below code for more information.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="blahblah">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="placeID" CssClass="ddlPlaceID">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                [...]
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The problem is, the list does not drop down when pressed on an iPad/iPhone device. It works mighty fine on a desktop however. I'm quite the rookie with asp.net, so I am sure that the answer is why it doesn't work is obvious.

Comment: It is possible that its a CSS issue. Sometimes bad styles can affect functionality by preventing things to be clicked because of issues with overlap, z-index, opacity, etc. This is especially a problem on mobile when everything gets crunched together. Nothing you have provided above would prevent your dropdown from working on iOS. Try inspecting your styles on a mobile viewport.

Comment: Try to isolate the issue.  If you remove the CssClass does it make any difference?